# NetBeans Java Application .jar file is not opening

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I really tried everything (changing the main class in the manifest as

"Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: downloadımages.NewJFrame"

and "clean and build main project" many times) but when I double click on .jar file in dist folder, nothing happens, even a error message. However, program works well in NetBeans compiler. Any idea?

Comment: Have you set the main class in the project properties?

Comment: Drop to the command line and run `java -jar {yourjar}` from within the `dist` directory